# Exact Job scheduling doesn't work when App is killed for long time (>1 min) on One Plus 5T(Nougat)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, android-job

I am trying to show a notification once a day at exact time. I am using Evernote Android Job library for this https://github.com/evernote/android-job. The time is coming from backend API. Below code is working fine when app is in foreground or background. But when app is killed for long time (~1min) or after reboot I am not getting notification on One Plus 5T(Nougat) and also on Oppo device(Mashmallow). Also, sometimes when I relaunch the app, I get all the failed notifications at once. Everything's working fine on Asus Zenfone Max (Mashmallow). Alarms are triggering in every scenario in Asus (foreground, background, screen locked or even reboot)

**Below is adb log for One Plus 5T**

**//when app is killed and before alarm scheduled time**

```
Shikhars-MacBook-Pro:HOGAndroid_New shikhardeep$ adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep "com.tf.eros.faythTv"
    ELAPSED_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{3a8c0ae type 2 when 1118303576 com.tf.eros.faythTv}
      tag=*walarm*:com.tf.eros.faythTv/com.evernote.android.job.v14.PlatformAlarmReceiver
      operation=PendingIntent{e233e4f: PendingIntentRecord{217c9dc com.tf.eros.faythTv broadcastIntent}}
    ELAPSED_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{44439ba type 2 when 1118303589 com.tf.eros.faythTv}
      tag=*walarm*:com.tf.eros.faythTv/com.evernote.android.job.v14.PlatformAlarmReceiver
      operation=PendingIntent{a7f706b: PendingIntentRecord{a45a7c8 com.tf.eros.faythTv broadcastIntent}}
  u0a355:com.tf.eros.faythTv +1s718ms running, 4 wakeups:
      *walarm*:com.tf.eros.faythTv/com.evernote.android.job.v14.PlatformAlarmReceiver
```

**//when app is killed and just after the alarm scheduled time**

```
Shikhars-MacBook-Pro:HOGAndroid_New shikhardeep$ adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep "com.tf.eros.faythTv"
  u0a355:com.tf.eros.faythTv +1s722ms running, 6 wakeups:
      *walarm*:com.tf.eros.faythTv/com.evernote.android.job.v14.PlatformAlarmReceiver
```

### Code

```
public class ShowHoroscopeNotificationJob extends Job {

public static final String TAG = "HOROSCOPE_NOTIFICATION";

public ShowHoroscopeNotificationJob() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void onReschedule(int newJobId) {
    super.onReschedule(newJobId);
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Params params) {
    try {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), "HOG_NOTIFICATION")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setContentTitle("Horoscope Reminder")
                        .setContentText("Check out Daily Horoscope !!!")
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(40) + 1, mBuilder.build()); 
            schedule(getExactTime(ZPreferences.getHoroscopeReminderTime(getContext()))); //again calling schedule() as setExact() can't be periodic 
            return Result.SUCCESS;
       }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return Result.RESCHEDULE;
    }
}

public static void schedule(long exactInMs) {

    if (exactInMs != 0L) {

        new JobRequest.Builder(ShowHoroscopeNotificationJob.TAG)
                .setExact(exactInMs)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?  I am also facing same issue.

Comment: no..try using WorkManager. It's part of Android. This problem occurs mostly in chinese phones like One Plus, Oppo, Vivo

Comment: can we schedule workmanager for specific date and time as like alarm manager?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299814/how-to-schedule-notifications-using-workmanager/55706333#55706333. According to this link AlarmManager is best choice but other answers also mention WorkManager

Comment: I tried with Work Manager but in One Plus 6T it is not working when Application is killed. (in background). Can you help me in this?

Comment: try this: https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6