# Android Alarm Manager not working with specific date and time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So I have been working on medication intake app, where I need to remind the user locally ( no internet/push notification needed) about taking their medication.
I am using Android Alarm manager for this. Below is the code
Note I am trying to schedule the alarm for a specific date: **"13 July 2018 at 3h30 PM"**. I schedule and wait but the reminder didn't fire (so not broadcast) however if I used **AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP** with a defined amount of millisecond it does fire ( **but AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP** just does not work)
`

```
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    long reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds = 000;

    myIntent = new Intent(this,MedicationScheduleBroadCastReceiver.class);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //TODO : Reminder the user to take medication on the 13th July 2018 at 15:30
    Calendar calendarToSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendarToSchedule.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
    calendarToSchedule.set(Calendar.MONTH, 07);
    calendarToSchedule.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);
    calendarToSchedule.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendarToSchedule.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds = calendarToSchedule.getTimeInMillis();

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
    }
    else{

        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
    }

`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I figure out the issue, the main issue was the calendar month in Java is actually 0 index based so ( Jan:0 - Dec:11) so below is the updated code.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent myIntent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
long reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds = 000;

myIntent = new Intent(this,MedicationScheduleBroadCastReceiver.class);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//TODO : Reminder the user to take medication on the 13th July 2018 at 15:30
// Note: For the month of July the int value will actuall be 6 instead of 7
Calendar calendarToSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarToSchedule.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendarToSchedule.clear();

//.Set(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minutes, Seconds);
calendarToSchedule.set(2018, 06, 13, 15, 30, 0);


reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds = calendarToSchedule.getTimeInMillis();

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

    manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
}
else{

    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderDateTimeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Better use Calendar.getInstance(); with custom or default Locale: Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()); Nice answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much!! I've been stuck on this for days now... It finally works now, phew!

Answer (score 0):

Alarms are not fired if device is in [**Doze mode**](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby). Use `setAndAllowWhileIdle` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` for alarms to be fired in Doze mode also.

From the [**Android Doc**](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

- Network access is suspended.
- The system ignores wake locks.
- Standard AlarmManager alarms (including `setExact()` and `setWindow()`) are
  deferred to the next maintenance window. If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.
- Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.
- The system does not perform Wi-Fi scans.
- The system does not allow sync adapters to run. The system does not allow JobScheduler to
  run.

Comment: But as you can see for all devices/emulator that have API level 26 and above I am actually using what you have mentioned "setExactAndAllowWhileIdle" and FYI I am testing on a device that have Android Oreo but still can't get it to fire

Comment: You can see work manager, i have switched to WorkManger from AlarmManager (due to unreliable behaviour)

Comment: but what I am trying to accomplish, it is apparently  more appropriate to use AlarmManager to do it than workManager, see below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299814/how-to-schedule-notifications-using-workmanager

Comment: Yes thanks for correcting me, Your requirement needs Alarm Manager.

Comment: Let me test your case, I'll get back to you.

Comment: I think that you should be using setAlarmClock() because while setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() can fire during doze maintenance windows, it is still subject to delays...[setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is not exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110246/setexactandallowwhileidle-is-not-exact-as-of-developer-reference)

Comment: @Elletlar this did not help.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more? what is causing issue.?