# Send Local Notifications in Android API 26

Tags: android, notifications, background-process, scheduler, android-8.0-oreo

I want to schedule simple local notifications in my Android app.

This was working fine when I was targeting API 24, but since I have to move to the last API in order to be able to update my app, I have to change some things in my code.

**Currently**, I use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and a simple `Service` to send the notification.

Every time I want to send a notification, I send an `Intent` to my `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` with all the info, and in the `onReceive` method I create a service and call `startWakefulService(context, service);`.

The `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` ensures that the process is not killed and the service does the heavy job in the background before firing the notification.

But now with the new **background limitations** of the last Android versions, I cannot simply start a service when my app is in the background, so every attempt to send a notification crashes my app: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service: app is in background**.
I also noticed that `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is now deprecated.

**When the alarm is set:**

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, NotifBroadcastReceiver.class);
// ...
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idNotification, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    millis, interval, alarmIntent);
```

**When the alarm is received: (in the NotifBroadcastReceiver class)**

```
// onReceive method
startWakefulService(context, service);
// the service then does the heavy job and fires the notification...
```

**My Questions:**

1. How can I use a simple `BroadcastReceiver` (instead of a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`) to send the notification by ensuring that CPU stays awake the whole process?
2. How can I change my code to do the heavy work the background service now does?

I've read about the `JobScheduler`, but it seems that it cannot be used in this case, since **it cannot garantee me that it will run in the exact time**.

The notifications are a very important part of my app, so if they're not fired anymore the app is practically useless...

Comment: refer WorkManager it is latest for background service.https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: WorkManager is not suited for jobs that happen at a particular time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299814/how-to-schedule-notifications-using-workmanager

Comment: Another example for Workmanager: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363541/schedule-a-work-on-a-specific-time-with-workmanager?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `IntentJobService` as it's the same as `Service` for Pre-O and uses `Jobs` for Android O.